# How to manipulate DOM both after server-side and client-side rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Here is my code (it is a Vue component in a Nuxt app):

```html
<template>
  <div class="comment-editor" v-if="loggedIn">
    <div class="leftside">
      <!-- <client-only> -->
      <textarea
        ref="editor"
        v-model="content"
        placeholder="your comment"
      ></textarea>
      <!-- </client-only> -->
      <Message v-bind="message" />
    </div>
    <Button
      text="Publish"
      color="main"
      v-if="message.type != 'loading'"
      @click="publish"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="notLoggedIn" v-else>
    You should <nuxt-link to="/signup">register</nuxt-link> or
    <nuxt-link to="/login">log in</nuxt-link> to write comments.
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const tx = document.querySelector("textarea");
    fh(tx);
    tx.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    tx.addEventListener("input", function () {
      fh(this);
    });
    function fh(x) {
      while (x.style.height + "" != x.scrollHeight + "px")
        x.style.height = x.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

What you can see in the "mounted" function is used to dynamically change the height of a textarea. It works properly when the component is client-side rendered (i.e. when navigating from another page), but the app crashes after SSR (when directly opening the page with the component). How to make that code work properly in both cases?

Comment: First off, you should probably not use JS to fix a height here, but rely on CSS. Then, why are you declaring a `editor` ref if you're not using it? Prefer using [`$refs`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) rather than query selectors. Also, it's probably a bad idea to use a `while` since it's blocking and that nothing should really **need** it on the frontend. `mounted()` is executed only on the client, so I'm not sure why it crashes here. Looks okay at first. Do you have a [repro] maybe? Would greatly help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when the component was mounted, initially, the class="leftside" element was not part of the dom (due to loggedIn being equal to false). The solution was to move the class="leftside" element and the mounted() function to a separate component.

Comment: The issue is beyond just that actually. As explained in my comment, there are a few things to fix here. You should try to stick to the Vue API. As told here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70456948/8816585

Answer (score 1):

You should use dynamic styling instead of direct DOM manipulations.

E.g., `<textare :style="{ height: computedHeight }" />`

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1